# Recovering Single File from Corrupted Image File

Tags: file-recovery

I have an disc image from a virtual machine that was deleted and then partially overwritten, and I'm still hoping to get a file off of it. The file in concern is very small (a few kilobytes) on a multi-gigabyte drive, so my chances are good, but I simply don't know what tools I should be using to access that image.

I've used Recuva to recover as much of the image as is possible; where should I go from here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the kind of file and what you know about its content, different tools might be useful. [PhotoRec](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Download) is a program that can find files in a lot of different [formats](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/File_Formats_Recovered_By_PhotoRec) by their header alone.
So if for example you are looking for a jpeg, and the file indeed hasn't been overwritten or deleted and is in a contiguous area within the disk image (which is highly likely for a file only a few kilobyte in size), photorec should be able to find it, and extract it from the image file.
The filename might be lost though.

If [PhotoRec](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Download) doesn't help [this list](http://www.forensicswiki.org/wiki/Tools:Data_Recovery) might contain a tool that does.

If some text string or something similar is known from the file, directly searching for that in the image file might work too.